# Deleting a pointer which contains a pointer pointing to another location

Tags: c++, pointers, data-structures, stack, c++14

Recently while I was writing code for Stack implementation. I came across this doubt. Please help me get through this. The code is written as shown below.

```
struct Stack{
  int top;
  int capacity;
  int *array;
}

Stack* createStack(int capacity){
  Stack *S = new Stack;

  S->capacity = capacity;
  S->top = -1;
  S->array = new int[capacity];

  return S;
}

void Delete(Stack *S){
  delete S->array;
  delete S;
}
```

Now my doubt lies here in the delete function. As we can see that the S is pointing to a memory block of type Stack. Inside which there is another pointer pointing to an array of blocks of type int.
**What would happen when the S block is deleted directly without deleting the array block?**

Comment: You would have a memory leak and if you keep doing that you will run out of memory. Is that the answer you are looking for? Btw. your code has undefined behavior, because you use `delete` on a pointer allocated by an array `new` expression. You must use `delete[]` instead.

Comment: This is why classes (and that includes things marked `struct`) have destructors. `~Stack()` should delete `array`. But `Stack` needs constructors and member functions, too. This code is C written in C++, i.e., the worst of both worlds.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> What would happen when is delete the S block directly without deleting the array block?

The `S` object would be destroyed and that memory would be released. Nothing else would happen. In particular, the memory pointed by `array` would not be released. If the member was the only pointer to that memory, then it will be impossible to release it. This is called a memory leak.

P.S. Behaviour of the program is undefined if `delete` is used on a pointer that was not returned by `new`. In the example program, `delete` is used on a pointer returned by `new[]`. The behaviour of the program is undefined. `delete[]` must be used instead.